# How to load a user profile using entity_metadata_wrapper in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, entity, user-profile

I am trying to get the user profile loaded with entity_metadata_wrapper:

```
$user_profile = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $uid);
dpm($user_profile);
```

but I get nothing back. The user fields load fine with user_load($uid); What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

entity_metadata_wrapper expects second parameter to be an object, in this case, user object. According to your variable naming, it seems that you are passing user id instead. You can use [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7) to fetch user object by ID.

Comment: The method explicitly says:  
// If the passed entity is the global $user, we load the user object by only
    // passing on the user id. The global user is not a fully loaded entity.
    if ($type == 'user' && is_object($data) && $data == $GLOBALS['user']) {
      $data = $data->uid;
    }

So I see that it uses uid anyway.

Comment: The function uses uid internally to load user data $data = $data->uid; in case it is global $user object, so it always expects an object (either user object or global user), you can write your own wrapper function if you are so eager to use uid, but the fact is - this function will return you nothing if you pass uid and you can clearly see it in the code you've pasted.

Answer (score 9):

The information provided by Linas is provably incorrect. The use of `entity_metadata_wrapper` with an entity id is completely okay. The function uses `uid` internally only if you pass an object to it to begin with, otherwise it passes the argument directly to `EntityDrupalWrapper`.

Eventually the [`set`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21includes%21entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityDrupalWrapper%3A%3Aset/7) method will be called, which states: "Overridden to support setting the entity by either the object or the id."

This basic code will demonstrate a working call to `entity_metadata_wrapper` with just a user id.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', 1);
dpm($wrapper->value());
```

The output will be an array of all the data belonging to the admin user.

The problem you are having is unrelated to your arguments being passed in (assuming `$uid` is valid), and requires more information to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem the code not work return empty  (Object) EntityDrupalWrapper

```
global $user;
$user_profile = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user->uid);
dpm($user_profile);
```

But that code work well and return  (Object) stdClass with all users fields like name password and other

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
dpm($wrapper->value());
```

Comment: You need to use `dpm($user_profile->value());` in your example. If you changed your second example to `dpm($wrapper);` you would see the same empty EntityDrupalWrapper.